# Sonoff RF Bridge to Mosquitto (on Windows) Configuration

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto, tasmota

I've been searching high and low for a simple explanation for this. What configuration settings do I use to connect my Sonoff RF bridge to the Mosquitto server on my computer? I'm sure it's a configuration issue but most of the tutorials out there are for rPi. My skill level in this is basic and I'm sure it may be obvious to someone what's wrong.

I'm running Mosquitto on Windows 10 and have verified that the Mosquitto server is running using netstat -a (I can see the broker is listening at 0.0.0.0:1883.

I've installed Tasmota Eclipse on my Sonoff RF Bridge and have verified it is receiving signal from my door sensor by opening the UI in my browser and viewing the console.   I've tried multiple host addresses in the configuration menu; localhost, 0.0.0.0, 10.0.0.1, however Tasmota only seems to connect when I leave the host field blank.

I've tried to use MQTTlens to verify that the broker is receiving messages on port 1883 and nothing seems to be coming through.

[image: Photo of Tasmota Configuration]
[image: Photo of MQTTLense Configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is a short hand to tell mosquitto to listen on all the available interfaces on the machine it is running on. It is meaningless to use it in the client configuration.

Likewise, `localhost` always means the same machine that the code making the request is running on, so in this case it would be the Sonoff device it's self.

It looks like `10.0.0.1` is the address of your local router, unless mosquitto is actually running on the router (it is very unlikely your windows machine is your router) this again is not going to be useful.

You need to use the IP address of the Windows machine that mosquitto is running on, this is going to start with `10.0.0`. running `ipconfig` on the command line in windows is probably the quickest/simplest way to find that address.